# How to debug Run-Time Check Failure #2?

Tags: c, debugging, struct, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging

When running the following code to calculate the probability of no pair, one pair, two pair, three of a kind, full house and four of a kind in a random seven-card poker hand, Visual Studio returns the warning "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'hand_counts' was corrupted" on the last line. However, the program can still output the results by clicking "Continue". I have checked the program for out-of-bounds array accesses, but have not found any. What could be causing the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum suit
{
    spades,
    hearts,
    diamonds,
    clubs
} suit;
typedef struct card
{
    suit suit;
    short pip;
} card;
void deck_shuffle(card deck[52])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        const int j = rand() % 52;
        const card temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
    }
}
int possibility(card hand[7])
{
    int pair_type = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (hand[i].pip == hand[j].pip)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    // check for no pairs.
    if (count == 0)
    {
        pair_type = 1;
    }
    // check for one pair.
    if (count == 1)
    {
        pair_type = 2;
    }
    // check for two pair.
    if (count == 2)
    {
        pair_type = 3;
    }
    // check for three of a kind.
    if (count == 3)
    {
        pair_type = 4;
    }
    // check for full house.
    int rank1 = 0;
    int rank2 = 0;
    int temp1 = hand[0].pip;
    int temp2;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (hand[i].pip == hand[j].pip)
            {
                rank1 = hand[j].pip;
                if (temp1 == rank1)
                {
                    count1++;
                    temp1 = rank1;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp2 = rank2;
                    rank2 = hand[j].pip;
                    if (temp2 == rank2)
                    {
                        count2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    count2 += 1;
    if ((count1 == 3 && count2 == 1) || (count1 == 3 && count2 == 3))
    {
        pair_type = 5;
    }
    // check for four of a kind.
    if (count1 == 6 || count2 == 6)
    {
        pair_type = 6;
    }
    return pair_type;
}
int main(void)
{
    card deck[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        deck[i].suit = i / 13;
        deck[i].pip = i % 13;
    }
    int hand_counts[6] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        deck_shuffle(deck);
        card hand[7];
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            hand[j] = deck[j];
        }
        int hand_type = possibility(hand);
        hand_counts[hand_type - 1]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("The probability of hand type %d: is %f\n", i + 1, (double)hand_counts[i] / 1000000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried running the same code in other IDEs, and there were no warnings. The results were also calculated faster than in Visual Studio. I am not sure if there is an error in my source code, or if it is a problem with Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Check if none of the array indexes of `hand_counts` gets out of bounds.

Comment: Hint: if your code appears to run fine on one developement platform but not on another one, this is a very strong indication that the problem is within _your_ code and not within the platform. Google "C undefined habaviour". An index going out of range results im undefined behaviour.

Comment: `possibility()` returns `hand_type` equal to 0 to 6, but then you do `hand_counts[hand_type - 1]++;`, so on 0 you're overwriting memory from somewhere else, which is undefined behaviour. Also, search here or Google for a simpler but more thorough shuffling algorithm.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Thank you for your help! I'm still trying to figure out the specific combination of 7 poker cards that doesn't meet the conditions for checking for a pair or other, but I think that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the multiple loops and variables toward the end of `possibility()` are somewhat difficult to follow. I stripped things down somewhat and put in a particular test case; 4 aces:

```
int possibility( int hand[7]) {
    int pair_type = 0;

    /* ... */

    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) printf( "%d ", hand[k] );

    int rank1 = 0;
    int rank2 = 0;
    int temp1 = hand[0];
    int temp2;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++) {
            if (hand[i] == hand[j]) {
                rank1 = hand[j];
                if (temp1 == rank1) {
                    count1++;
                    temp1 = rank1;
                } else {
                    temp2 = rank2;
                    rank2 = hand[j];
                    if (temp2 == rank2)
                        count2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    count2 += 1;
    printf( "\nSuspicion: count1 = %d count2 = %d\n", count1, count2 );
    /* ... */
    return pair_type;
}

int main(void) {
    int hand[7] = { 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 };

    printf("hand type %d\n", possibility(hand) );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
12 0 0 0 0 1 2
Suspicion: count1 = 0 count2 = 7   // <<<<
hand type 0
```

Then:

```
        int hand_type = possibility(hand);
        hand_counts[hand_type - 1]++;
```

Will increment the location `hand_counts[ 0 - 1 ]`... Definitely a No-No.

You need to go back to that nested `for()` loop and figure out how to avoid *double counting*. 4-of-a-kind can occur in any locations. There's too much *double counting* happening in your loops.

Suggest you look into "histogram" tallying of the cards (`int cnt[13] = {0};` would be a start. Then a single pass over the hand will give you the tallies you need.

"*or if it is a problem with Visual Studio itself.*" While that's always a possibility, it's a poor craftsman who starts by blaming his/her tools.

---

Y'know... If you'd not tried to use an array dimensioned for precisely 6-and-only-6 "types", then gone on to subtract 1 to use 0-based indexing, you might have caught this yourself...

```
int hand_counts[ 27 ] = { 0 }; // why not?
/* ... */
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof hand_counts/sizeof hand_counts[0]; i++)
    {
        printf("The probability of hand type %d: is %f\n", i, (double)hand_counts[i] / 1000000);
    }
```

(Just noticed you "add 1" in your print statement! Too much "clever" overflows to become "dumb"...)

---

**Overtime:**
Intrigued, here's a stripped down version that may be suitable for elaborating into something bigger:

```
void deck_shuffle( int deck[] ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
        const int j = rand() % 52;
        const int temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
    }
}

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    return *(int*)b - *(int*)a; // descending sqnc
}

enum { nada, four, three, two, twoPair, fullhouse, nTallies };

int possibility( int hand[] ) {
    int cnt[13] = { 0 };

    for( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
        printf( "%c ", "A234567890JQK"[ hand[i] ] );
        ++cnt[ hand[i] ];
    }

//  qsort( cnt, sizeof cnt[0], 13, cmp ); // Wrong!
    qsort( cnt, 13, sizeof cnt[0], cmp ); // descending

    if( cnt[0] == 4 ) return four;

    if( cnt[0] == 3 )
        if( cnt[1] == 2 )
            return fullhouse;
        else
            return three;

    if( cnt[0] == 2 )
        if( cnt[1] == 2 )
            return twoPair;
        else
            return two;

    return nada;
}

int main( void ) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int deck[52];

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        deck[i] = i % 13;

    int hand_counts[ nTallies ] = { 0 };

    for( int r = 0; r < 100; r++ ) {
        deck_shuffle( deck );

        int p = possibility( deck ); // look at top 7 cards
        printf( " ... %2d\n", p );

        ++hand_counts[ p ];
    }

    for( int out = 0; out < nTallies; out++ )
        printf("The probability of hand type %d: is %f\n", out, (double)hand_counts[out] / 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis. I really appreciate it. I realize now that I didn't think my code through carefully enough, and that's what caused the problem. It seems that I need to carefully analyze the code before asking questions in the future.

Comment: @PRACTICALPIG It fills the time. First analysis I did was hasty and not applicable. Went back to your code and tried again. Just added a "lite version" that you may find interesting. Card "suits" are a distraction. Test the h*ll out of the logic first, before adding flourishes. It's all a learning curve... `:-)`

Comment: @PRACTICALPIG Discovered my usual slip-up. Wrong order of parameters to `qsort()`. Hope this hasn't caused you any lost time...

Comment: I am very grateful. I think your approach is easier to understand and can solve the problem better. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @PRACTICALPIG Forgotten more poker than I ever knew... Just asked Google "Winning poker hands" to learn there are 10 categories, some not being "suit agnostic" (eg: a "flush", royal or otherwise.) It might be clearest to use a loop, checking, from the highest value, the best "hand" that the cards could form. No-one would want to claim 4 aces as "2 pair", right? `:-)` (`qsort()` could be a very good friend in this!)

Comment: @PRACTICALPIG With time to fill, I've reworked the code to use an _interesting_ mapping of card values. It's about 130 lines, and includes a "self-test" of each possible hand (used to check its functionality.) Let me know if you're interested and I could post my "hacky" code for all to see. Cheers! `:-)`